# How to handle browser authentication pop up within application using selenium webdriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am automating test cases for an application which requires an authentication to launch homepage. I am using below code to make it work.

```
String url = "http://i.user:i.password@baseURL_1/home";
driver.get(url);
```

Once I am inside the application , there is another link called "*workflow*" , clicking on which opens another application of same system. i.e. it redirects to 
http://baseURL_2/home.

While opening page from second application , browser(Chrome) authentication window re-appears.
How do I handle it in automation script?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);      
Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());     
alert.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword(username, password));
```

Comment: I think this is only for selenium 3.4 and implemented only for Internet explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I see you've tried to pass the username and password within the URL. I had a similar issue a while back, the resolution for me was to whitelist my IP, this means the website wont request a username and password when you visit.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am not aware of how to whitelist an IP. Can you share that info.

Comment: One of the developers did this for me in work, I assume you are doing this for work purposes? Give one of them a shout and they should be able to do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
alert.SetAuthenticationCredentials("username", "password");
alert.Accept();
```